# Sending GET Request with fragment identifier in Python

Tags: python, html, url, get

I'm trying to send a GET request using the requests module including a fragment identifier. I have the following code:

```
url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p20_quantity_desc'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

However I always end up getting the base page (http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730) instead of the page with the fragment identifier (the #p20_quanitity_description doesn't seem to be sent).

urllib2 also isn't working for me with the code:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read().decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
```

How would I go about sending a GET request and including the #p20_quanitity_description in the URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anchor (`p20_quantity_desc`) means nothing to the server. There's a bit of Javascript on the page that's changing the sort order of the results based on this anchor, but this is client-side. Requests/urllib will see the same page response with or without the anchor.

Try disabling Javascript on the page and you'll see what I mean.

What you want to do instead is make a request to the API endpoint that the page is using. Here's an example:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=0&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=quantity&sort_dir=asc&appid=730
```

Note the `sort_column` argument? This is the value you can change to decide the ordering of the results. Use a library like lxml to parse the `results_html` field and presto, you're done.

Comment: This answer is correct. The fragment identifier should in fact never be sent to the server by a user agent, see [Architecture of the World Wide Web | 3.2.1. Representation types and fragment identifier semantics](http://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/#media-type-fragid) or [RFC3986 §3.5](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) for example.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for the explanation. How exactly do you find the API the page is using (in case I wanted to try some other site)? Did you just know this about how the Steam website works or is there a way I can find out what a given website is loading?

Comment: @acfman17 the [Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox or [Chrome's developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) are your friends. Both have a "network" tab that allows you to display all requests your browser makes (and their parameters).