# requests.get(url) returns the content of another webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am encountering some issues when trying to web-scrap this [webpage](https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/match-direct/ligue-1/2020-2021/ol-dijon-live/477168#face-a-face) (target). I always get the content of this [webpage](https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/match-direct/ligue-1/2020-2021/ol-dijon-live/477168) (main). Actually, when [URL_target](https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/match-direct/ligue-1/2020-2021/ol-dijon-live/477168#face-a-face) loads, during 0.5 second, the content of [URL_main](https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/match-direct/ligue-1/2020-2021/ol-dijon-live/477168) is displayed and after that, the "real" URL_target content is displayed. I guess this is why I cannot get the final content when web-scraping [URL_target](https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/match-direct/ligue-1/2020-2021/ol-dijon-live/477168#face-a-face).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url_main = "https://www.lequipe.fr/Football/match-direct/ligue-1/2020-2021/ol-dijon-live/477168"
url_target = url_main + "#face-a-face"
soup_main = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_main, verify=False).content, "html.parser")
soup_target = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_target, verify=False).content, "html.parser")
print(soup_main == soup_target)
```

returns `True`.

Does someone know how could I get the "real" content of `url_target` ? Thanks !

Comment: Fragment/hash isn't sent to the server or is just ignored by it. And you can't get dynamically loaded content like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending GET Request with fragment identifier in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024875/sending-get-request-with-fragment-identifier-in-python)

Comment: @gre_gor Yes indeed, this guy has the same issue. But the answer he got is not very general. I don't know where can I find this mysterious URL I should request...

Comment: @RillettesBoy, what data are you actually trying to pull from there?

Comment: Everything on the page. For instance, everything in the section "confrontations depuis 2011" : "6, 2 nuls, 2"... and all the sections below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to solve your problem but I might have an idea about what it's causing this issue, the '#face-face' is an hashlink wich the js in the page uses to load a specific part of the website, and BeautifoulSoup might have some problem with this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).